# using url in a string in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to convert urls in a string to workable urls. For example:
    str = "Hello, this is the link for yahoo: http://www.yahoo.com"

```
//in the view i have
<%= parse_description(r[:description]) %>

//in helper, i am splitting each word in the string and verifying if i have a string which
//  contains http, if http is present then i am using link_to to make it a valid url:
def parse_description(str)
  s = ""
    str.split.each do |w|
       a =  w.include?("http") ? (link_to nil,"#{w}") : w
       s += "#{a} "
    end 
end
```

once the string is returned back to the view, the link is not clickable. what wrong i am doing?

Comment: Well, what is the value returned? How might that (along with how it is used) make a difference? Inspect the generated HTML for ideas.

Comment: basically it just returns the string that i am sending, but i want the yahoo link to be a valid url on the view.

Comment: And how do you make a link in HTML?

Comment: @Kumar So, back to my comment: *"Inspect the generated HTML for ideas"*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks pst for your help.. while returning i just did s.html_safe.. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To match the URI's in a String use the following code:

```
html_string.scan(URI.regexp) do |*matches|
  p $&
end
```